# How to configure Chromium or Chrome with Incognito Mode as default

Tags: macos, google-chrome, language

I would like to configure Chrome/Chromium with Incognito Mode as default. Could you tell me about it?

*** Reason: ***

I have Google account with Chrome, When I search keyword in English on internet with default Language setting as Japanese. The search keyword seems be translated in Japanese automatically and get results in Japanese. If I use incognito mode, some setting is ignored then I can search and get results in English easily. So, I would like to run the browser by one click.

*** Requirements: ***

1. Keep Google Account authentication of Chrome with Language settings as Japanese.
2. Google search(https://www.google.com or co.jp) with English keyword and have results in English.
3. No change the configuration every time when I search in English
4. Implementing the requirements with Chrome or Chromium
5. Without making new account for New instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start it in incognito mode by default you just need to add the `-incognito` parameter to the target field of the Chrome properties (right-click on the Chrome icon > Shortcut tab > add `-incognito` after `chrome.exe`.

Alternatively, you could just use http://www.google.com/en

Sources:

[How to Start Google Chrome in Incognito Mode by Default](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-start-google-chrome-in-incognito-mode-by-default/)

[Setting Google results to stay in a language, regardless of location](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14435/setting-google-results-to-stay-in-a-language-regardless-of-location)

Comment: It worked! I'm very happy with this http://www.google.com/en.

Comment: @Juza Very good, I'm glad it solved your problem :)